# Delete item from MvxListView in Xamarin Android using MvvmCross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

So I have a list of slides:

SlideListView.axml:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/slidelistitem"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Slides" />
```

SlideListItemView.axml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/block"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="Test text" />

  <Button
    style="@style/ButtonSlide"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So each slide has a text and delete button.

SlideListItemViewModel.cs:

```
public class SlideListItemViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private long _id;
    private string _title;

    public long Id { get => _id; set => SetProperty(ref _id, value); }

    public string Title { get => _title; set => SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
}
```

in `SlideListItemViewModel` I can't have a constructor because of automapper needs default empty constructor... So the problem is that I need to bind delete command to `SlideListViewModel`. I don't know how can I do that... What more I have to do so all the delete logic would be in`SlideListViewModel` and not in `SlideListItemViewModel`?

**UPDATE 1**

That's where I create my `SlideListItemViewModel`

```
public class SlideListViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigation;
    private ICollection<SlideListItemViewModel> _slides;

    public ICollection<SlideListItemViewModel> Slides { get => _slides; set => SetProperty(ref _slides, value); }

    public SlideListViewModel(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
    {
        _navigation = navigation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you create SlideListItemViewModel? Can't you pass a parent to the model from there?

Comment: @Cheesebaron updated my question. And no can't pass parent to the model

Comment: @NikasŽalias can you please see if my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show you how I use in my project and you adapt into your:

1) Create a class that "wrap" you entity and a command:

```
public class EntityWrap<T>
{
    private Action<T> _realPrimaryCommand { get; set; }

    public T Entity { get; set; }
    public ICommand PrimaryCommand { get; set; }

    public EntityWrap(T entity, Action<T> realPrimaryCommand)
    {   
        Entity = entity;
        _realPrimaryCommand = realPrimaryCommand;
        PrimaryCommand = new MvxCommand(() => _realPrimaryCommand(entity));
    }
}
```

2) My book class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set }

    public Book(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

3) In viewmodel:

```
public BooksViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public BooksViewModel()
    {
        var books = new List<Book>() { new Book(1, "AAA"), new Book(2, "BBB"), new Book(3, "CCC") };
        Books = new ObservableCollection<EntityWrap<Book>>(books.Select(x => new EntityWrap<Book>(x, async y => await DoDeleteBookCommand(y))));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<EntityWrap<Book>> _books;
    public ObservableCollection<EntityWrap<Book>> Books
    {
        get { return _books; }
        set
        {
            _books = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Books);
        }
    }

    private async Task DoDeleteBookCommand(Book book)
    {
        var bookToRemove = Books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Entity.Id == book.Id);
        if (bookToRemove != null)
        {
            //Your code...
            Books.Remove(bookToRemove);
        }
    }
}
```

4) And in you item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      local:MvxBind="Text Entity.Name" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Delete"
        local:MvxBind="Click PrimaryCommand" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Don't set ItemClick on ListView/RecyclerView unless you have a command for the row click.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `MvxCommand` (called DeleteCommand for example) in your `SlideListItemViewModel`. It should publish a message using the [MvxMessenger Plugin](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger) when fired, indicating that the item needs to be deleted.

You need to bind this MvxCommand to your button using:

`local:MvxBind:"Click DeleteCommand"`

and finally you also need to subscribe to the message in your `SlideListViewModel` and remove the item from the list when a new message is received.